# Can I use Views Bulk Operations or something similar to create an archive of files generated by Views data export?

Tags: views, actions, importing-exporting

Using [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export), I have multiple CSV files generated/provided by several different displays.  Rather than setting up something where the user clicks a "Download CSV" button corresponding to each Views display, I'd like to have a single button where all of the files are zipped into a single archive file that is downloaded.

I know [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) has the ability to take multiple managed files and create a zip archive from them...  Is it possible to use custom actions or VBO somehow to achieve what I'm looking to do?  Or is there a better way to do something like this?  Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the patch from [#1436726](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export/issues/1436726) which adds VBO integration into Views Data Export module, however it's for Drupal 7.x.

```
diff --git a/views_data_export.module b/views_data_export.module
index 0a8c90b..9b7b784 100644
--- a/views_data_export.module
+++ b/views_data_export.module
@@ -272,6 +272,84 @@ function views_data_export_clear($export_id) {
   views_data_export_view_clear($export_id);
 }
 
+/**
+ * Implements hook_action_info().
+ */
+function views_data_export_action_info() {
+  return array(
+    'views_data_export_action_csv_export' => array(
+      'type' => 'entity',
+      'label' => t('Export to CSV'),
+      'configurable' => FALSE,
+      'aggregate' => TRUE,
+      'behavior' => array('views_data_export_export_csv'),
+    ),
+  );
+}
+
+/**
+ * CSV export action callback.
+ */
+function views_data_export_action_csv_export($entity, &$context) {
+
+  if (isset($context['view_info'])) {
+    $view = views_get_view($context['view_info']['name']);
+    $display_id = FALSE;
+
+    foreach ($view->display as $display) {
+      if ($display->display_plugin == 'views_data_export') {
+        $display_id = $display->id;
+        break;
+      }
+    }
+
+    if ($display_id) {
+      $args = array();
+      // If a subset of the available entities was selected, provide the list
+      // of selected IDs to the view as a contrived argument, which we'll
+      // use later to alter the query.
+      // Extra code for backward/forward compatibility.
+      // @see https://www.drupal.org/node/2488146.
+      if (isset($context['view_info']['total_rows'])) {
+        $total_rows = $context['view_info']['total_rows'];
+      }
+      else {
+        $countView = clone $view;
+        $countView->execute($context['view_info']['display']);
+        $total_rows = $countView->total_rows;
+      }
+      $entity_ids = array_keys($entity);
+      if (count($entity_ids) < $total_rows) {
+        $args['entity_ids'] = implode('+', $entity_ids);
+      }
+      $view->execute_display($display_id, $args);
+      // If the export is configured to run as a batch job, it will handle the
+      // display of progress & result/download pages, deliver the generated
+      // file, and never return here. Otherwise, executing the display here
+      // won't cause the file to be delivered to the browser for download.
+      // Dying here ensures that it does, but there must be a better way.
+      die();
+    }
+    else {
+      drupal_set_message(t("Can't export data, because the !view view does not have a !display display.", array('!view' => $view->name, '!display' => 'views_data_export')), 'error');
+    }
+  }
+}
+
+/**
+ * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
+ */
+function views_data_export_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
+  if ($view->display_handler->plugin_name == 'views_data_export') {
+    // If an explicit list of entity IDs was provided, use that to refine the
+    // query.
+    if (isset($view->args['entity_ids'])) {
+      $query->add_where(0, $view->base_table . '.' . $view->base_field, explode('+', $view->args['entity_ids']), 'IN');
+      // Now remove this fake argument to avoid confusion.
+      unset($view->args['entity_ids']);
+    }
+  }
+}
 
 /**
  * Store a view in the object cache.
```

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal >=8.x you can use [VBO export](https://www.drupal.org/project/vbo_export) module which extends [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

Then you can write your own plugin. Here is the example for a class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

/**
 * Generates ZIP with exported files.
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "vbo_export_generate_zip_action",
 *   label = @Translation("Generate ZIP from selected view results"),
 *   type = ""
 * )
 */
class VboExportZip extends \Drupal\vbo_export\Plugin\Action\VboExportBase {

  const EXTENSION = 'zip';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Settings for preliminary config.
   */
  public function buildPreConfigurationForm(array $form, array $values, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildPreConfigurationForm($form, $values, $form_state);
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Output generated string to file. Message user.
   *
   * @param string $output
   *   The string that will be saved to a file.
   */
  protected function sendToFile($output) {
    if (!empty($output)) {
      $rand = substr(hash('ripemd160', uniqid()), 0, 8);
      $filename = $this->context['view_id'] . '_' . date('Y_m_d_H_i', $this->time->getRequestTime()) . '-' . $rand . '.' . static::EXTENSION;

      $wrappers = $this->streamWrapperManager->getWrappers();
      if (isset($wrappers['private'])) {
        $wrapper = 'private';
      }
      else {
        $wrapper = 'public';
      }

      $destination = $wrapper . '://' . $filename;

      $zip = new \ZipArchive();

      foreach ($output as $row) {
        // Adding one file at once.
        $opened = $zip->open(drupal_realpath($destination), \ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

        if (!$opened) {
          // Error.
          $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Export failed!'));
          return;
        }

        $zip->addFile($row['file_path_abs'], $row['file_name']);
        $zip->close();
      }

      // ZIP file will be managed by Drupal. Also marking file as temporary.
      $file = File::create([
        'filename' => \basename($destination),
        'filemime' => 'application/zip',
        'uri' => $destination,
        'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
        'status' => 0,
      ]);
      $file->save();

      // Get relative url to prevent mixed content errors when using HTTPS + HTTP.
      $relative_url = \file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url($file->getFileUri()));
      $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Export file created, <a href=":url" target="_blank">Click here</a> to download.', [':url' => $relative_url]));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Generate output string.
   */
  protected function generateOutput() {
    $rows = $this->getRows();

    // Generate output.
    $output = [];

    // @todo: Customize below.
    $output[] = [
      'file_name' => strip_tags($row['some_file_field']),
      // 'file_url' => $attachment['url'],
      'file_path_abs' => str_replace(["\\", '//'], '/', $attachment['path']),
      'file_mime_type' => $attachment['mime_type'],
    ];

    return $output;
  }

}
```

Place the code under `src/Plugin/Action/` in your `my_module` module (e.g. `VboExportZip.php`). Ensure you've `php-zip` extension installed (e.g. `apt install php-zip`).